# Unable to read VR Path Registry - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am trying to execute a test case using Selenium and java but the page does not load completely and I am getting this message in my eclipse console:

> Unable to read VR Path Registry

What does this message mean?

Here is the code:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
try {
    driver.get(url);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(idName)));
...
```

Here is the console:

```
1513781293556   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
    Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\jo\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
    [Parent 12932, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
    Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\jo\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
    [Child 8784, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
    [Child 8784, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
    1513781295106   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54019
    1513781295991   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
    1513781296065   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 4294967297
    dic 20, 2017 3:48:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    1513781296124   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "beforeunload" for "about:blank"
    1513781297500   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pagehide" for "about:blank"
    1513781297501   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "unload" for "about:blank"
    1513781306755   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pageshow" for "[URL]"
    1513781311436   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "DOMContentLoaded" for "[URL]"
    Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\jo\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
    JavaScript warning: [URL]_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3&ns=46&cb=1899153169, line 1: unreachable code after return statement
    JavaScript warning:[URL]?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3&ns=46&cb=1899153169 line 1 > eval, line 1: unreachable code after return statement
    1513781320494   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pageshow" for "https://www.url.it/it/adesione?zoneid=home-box_offerta#!"
    1513781321091   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 4294967317
    test failure Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: ITA_IFM_First_Name__c (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
    Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\jo\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
    [Child 2004, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
    [Child 2004, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
```

Testing another site, there is no such problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to read VR Path Registry

that's not what is causing your failure.

There is a clear error message stating:

```
test failure Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: ITA_IFM_First_Name__c
```

You are waiting for visibility of the element with id "ITA_IFM_First_Name__c"... which doesn't appear before the timeout is reached.

Comment: I fixed it adding a cookie which made me displayed that object, do u know why Unable to read VR Path Registry showed up? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Download the required version of `gecodriver` from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). and initialize your `firefox` driver like below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/PATH/TO/geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: this is not the issue shown in the OP's stackstrace

Comment: @eeadev didn't you add this line  `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/PATH/TO/geckodriver.exe");` from this answer.

Comment: @Ali Azam, thank you but I dont think it was a matter of the driver

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue and it's resolved by using old gecko driver which is V0.19.1. I was lately using gecko driver v0.20.0

Answer (score 0):

I found same issue earlier but find not found any problem yet after using geckodriver-v0.19.1 currently.

Answer (score -1):

```
//set geckodriver path
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");

// Suppress logs with warning
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"/dev/null");

// initialize Firefox driver object to open Firefox browser
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Description of how this code answers the question would be helpful.